# How to bind data to list view from soap reponse in android

Tags: android, categories

I finally got data from soap response like this i want to parse this data to listview please help me

**My Code is**

```
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn; 

       SoapObject element1=(SoapObject) result.getProperty("CategoriasBO_ObtenerTodosResult");
       System.out.println("--------------element "+element1.toString());

       SoapObject element2=(SoapObject) element1.getProperty("diffgram");
       SoapObject docmntElmnt = (SoapObject) element2.getProperty("DocumentElement");
       System.out.println(docmntElmnt.getPropertyCount());


       for(int i=0;i<docmntElmnt.getPropertyCount();i++)
       {
        SoapObject table = (SoapObject)docmntElmnt.getProperty(i);
        System.out.println("-----Table data is---"+table.toString());

       }
```

**My soap response is**

```
-----Table datais---anyType{CategoriaID=8; Nombre=Bar & Restaurants;
Imagen1=/desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home8.png;
Imagen2=desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/bar-restaurants1.png;
Activa=true; }
07-12 09:17:31.164: INFO/System.out(205): -----Table data
is---anyType{CategoriaID=9; Nombre=Fashion & Beauty;
Imagen1=/desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home7.png;
Imagen2=desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/fashion-beauty2.png;
Activa=true; }
07-12 09:17:31.164: INFO/System.out(205): -----Table data
is---anyType{CategoriaID=10; Nombre=Party & Entertainment;
Imagen1=/desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home2.png;
Imagen2=desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/party-entertainment2.png;
Activa=true; }
07-12 09:17:31.164: INFO/System.out(205): -----Table data
is---anyType{CategoriaID=11; Nombre=Life & Style;
Imagen1=/desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/home/home3.png;
Imagen2=desktopmodules/guatsup/categorias/images/Categoria/life-style1.png;
Activa=true; }
```

Comment: madhu do u mean ?? that each of your elements return another set of record and you want to parse that one as well and you are having problems in parsing that ??? please reply

Answer (score 0):

What u need to do is Get the required elements String form the Soap Response like following:

```
  SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelop.getResponse();
  String element1 = result.getProperty("element name").toString();
```

This will store the element into your String Object.

Then Implement the ListView and for that u will be using ArrayList to add object into the list.

Then add the element1 object of Class String into the ArrayList for listview and u will be done.

Hope this helps.

For more information you can Ask Me.